# How to: cat text | ./script.pl

Tags: perl, readline

I started using `Term::Readline` recently, but now I realized `cat text | ./script.pl` doesn't work (no output).

script.pl snippet before (working ok):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;
while (<>) {
   print $_;
}
```

script.pl snippet after (working only interactively):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadLine

$| = 1;
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('name');
my $input;
while (defined ($input = $term->readline('')) ) {
   print $input;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to preserve this behavior (to have the lines printed) ?

Comment: If you want to read from STDIN, you'll need to read from STDIN. You could base the behaviour on `my $interactive = !@ARGV && -t STDIN;`

Comment: Classic example of Useless Use of Cat in your question title. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: You need to decide where you want to read from: if you use `readline` then it will always read from */dev/tty*.  If you use `<>` or the standard input, it may or may not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it up to use the input and output filehandles that you want.  The docs don't spell it out, but the constructor takes either a string (to serve as a name), or that string and globs for input and output filehandles (need both).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Term::ReadLine;

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('name', \*STDIN, \*STDOUT);

while (my $line = $term->readline()) {
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

Now

```
echo "hello\nthere" | script.pl
```

prints the two lines with `hello` and `there`, while `scipt.pl < input.txt` prints out the lines of the file `input.txt`. After this the normal `STDIN` and `STDOUT` will be used by the module's `$term` for all future I/O. Note that the module has methods for retrieving input and output filehandles  (`$term->OUT` and `$term->IN`) so you can change later where your I/O goes.

The [`Term::ReaLine`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ReadLine.html) itself doesn't have much detail but this is a front end for other modules, listed on the page. Their pages have far more information. Also, I believe that uses of this are covered elsewhere, for example in the good old `Cookbook`.